# Are there recovery options for a SSD drive which is not detected anymore?

Tags: linux, ssd, hardware-failure, ext4, hard-drive-recovery

The SSD drive on my laptop is not detected anymore, resulting in a "no bootable device" error at startup. If possible, I would like to recover some of the files from the drive.

I use Linux so the partitions are ext4 partitions. In case it matters: I already had this issue with this SSD a couple times before, and it was actually fine after simply re-connecting it. I was hoping this would be enough this time again, but no luck.

I tried to read the content using a USB drive enclosure for this type of drive (M2) on another computer. unfortunately the drive and/or partitions are not detected:

- `lsusb` detects the USB enclosure device correctly
- `lsblk` doesn't show any partition, neither `fdisk` nor the Disks utility finds the drive.

I'm aware that things don't look very good so far, but is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but if the drive is no longer detected it is dead. Simple as that.

Comment: Crucial suggest putting it in an enclosure and leaving it plugged in for some time https://uk.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/why-did-ssd-disappear-from-system

Comment: @DavidMarshall Some time? You mean 5 minutes? “Whether the drive is visible or not, let it sit in this state for a minimum of five minutes to allow the SSD to rebuild its mapping tables, then reboot the system and see if the drive is restored.” Seems like it is worth a shot if someone has an external enclosure and — most importantly — a second system to plug it into. But I wouldn’t hold my breath; assume the drive is dead and that efforts like what Crucial suggests are truly last chance efforts.

Comment: Its somewhat unlokely it can be tecovered without specialist tools and knowledge.  If the data is particularly valuable and not backed up data recovery specialists (who can unsolder chips etc) may be able to help with recovery.

Comment: There is no point - even if you managed to partially restore the disk to life, you couldn't trust it to keep any data, important or not. So why bother?

Comment: @DavidMarshall Thanks for the tip, I will try.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yes, I'm aware that there's very little chance of resuscitating it but since I can have access to an enclosure it doesn't hurt to try David's suggestion. I actually had a backup, I only lost a few days of stuff but if there's any way to get it I'd like to try.

Comment: @Erwan Makes sense if you can try it. Best of luck here!

Comment: @Erwan I know it's been a bit, but I'm curious: did the external enclosure trick work?

Comment: @Forgotten_User unfortunately it didn't in my case.